# Ember nested dynamic forms

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js but I decided to try it for my task. 
The task is to make a dynamic form builder: user should be able to add boxes with names and then insert field configs (which are forms) into that boxes.
Field configs are editable and they should be saved after edit.

In the backend I use Rails+AMS+Mongo and the data structure looks like that:

1. Company has one UsersProfileConfig
2. UsersProfileConfig has many BoxConfigs
3. BoxConfig has many FieldConfigs

[image]

In Ember I've already created models for BoxConfigs and FieldConfigs and basic routes for them. 
Now I feel stuck and don't know what to do next and whether it was a good idea to use Ember for that.
Could anyone suggest me workflow or next development steps?

Comment: I guess showing your code of what you have so far will be way better to help out than only a mockup ...

Comment: @intuitivepixel thanks for the answer. I've googled a lot since asking this question and now have nearly half of task done. But I will definitely have some concrete questions in future and then I'll show code.